# Color legend in scatter plots - not able to understand a code

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking to get deeper into scatter plots and trying to understand how to make diff color legend. From a tutorial on net, getting this snippet of code but not able to understand what it is doing.

```
# Prepare Data 
 # Create as many colors as there are unique midwest['category'] 
categories = np.unique(midwest['category']) 
colors = [plt.cm.tab10(i/float(len(categories)-1)) for i in range(len(categories))]
```

Answer (score 3):

The goal of a colormap is to map a number in the interval [0-1] to a color.

if one considers the `tab10` colormap, `plt.cm.tab10(0.0)` would return the color at the leftmost edge of the colormap, and `plt.cm.tab10(1.0)` returns the color at the rightmost edge.

[image]

Here, the user wants to get as many colors as there are categories (say `N`), so they generates `N` numbers equaly spaced in the interval [0-1].

For instance, if we suppose `categories` contains 4 elements, then

`[i/float(len(categories)-1) for i in range(len(categories))]`

returns

`[0.0, 0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666, 1.0]`

by passing each of those numbers to `plt.cm.tab10()`, those numbers are converted into 4 individual colors

`[plt.cm.tab10(i/float(len(categories)-1)) for i in range(len(categories))]`

returns

```
[(0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765, 1.0),
 (0.8392156862745098, 0.15294117647058825, 0.1568627450980392, 1.0),
 (0.8901960784313725, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7607843137254902, 1.0),
 (0.09019607843137255, 0.7450980392156863, 0.8117647058823529, 1.0)]
```

Note that this whole thing could be written much more compactly like so:

`plt.cm.tab10(np.linspace(0,1,len(categories)))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit assumption in this code that the number of unique categories is 10 or less, because `tab10` colormap only has 10 colors. Still, one would probably not call that colormap with equally distributed floats ranging from 0 to 1 in this case and it would also fail if there is only a single category present.

Instead one may choose a "categorical" colormap like `tab10` in case there is a lower number of colors, else choose one with more colors.

```
categories = np.unique(data)
if len(categories) <= 10: 
    colors = plt.cm.tab10(np.arange(len(categories)))
else:
    colors = plt.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0, 1, len(categories)))
```